# How do you render a realistic outdoor world with Gazebo?

Tags: gazebo-camera

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

How would you simulate an outdoor environment with the Gazebo simulator? e.g. I would need to provide a texture map of the ground, sky and background, so that the robot sees more than just a flat color shade. The [tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=build_world) explain how to populate a simple world with objects, but they all seem to assume I'm simulating an indoor environment with no background or special lighting conditions. I can't find how to texture the ground/sky/background to mimic an outdoor environment.

I'm thinking about participating in an autonomous vehicle competition, and I'm trying to find a way to simulate the course so I can easily test how my "virtual" robot reacts to camera input that roughly mimics input from the real course.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7474/how-do-you-render-a-realistic-outdoor-world-with-gazebo?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1031/cerin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 75 on 2014-11-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

Check out [this answer](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6459/blue-skies-in-gazebo-19/).

Take a look at the [`<scene>`](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.5&elem=scene) tag , you can add numerous stuff (sunrise, fog, clouds etc).

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2014-11-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1031/cerin/) on 2014-11-18**:
Thanks, but that doesn't completely answer my question. I need to apply specific textures, possibly sampled from satellite images or video. I don't see anything in the  tag docs for specifying texture, only lighting and some generic atmospheric settings.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can use a [terrain](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=dem&cat=build_world) with custom textures.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-11-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [green96](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1016/green96/) on 2014-11-20**:
Hi, this solution only works with Gazebo 3? Is there any solution or trick to add terrain map or to get similar effect in Gazebo 2.2?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2014-11-20**:
You can use a 3D collada mesh. Or apply a texture to the ground plane (if a flat surface is acceptable).